# Синхронизация межпроцесcного доступа к коду C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, просматривал такие понятия как Mutex, Semaphore, SemaphoreSlim, AutoResentEvent и т.д. В ходе разбирательств с ними возникли вот такие вопросы:
1) Если не дать Mutex имя, получается, что он начинает работать как обычный lock делать синхронизацию между потоками на уровне одного процесса, а межпроцессная синхронизация пропадает? То есть в таком случаи он ни чем не отличается от lock?
2) Вопрос похожий на предыдущий, Semaphore без задания имени он превращается в обычный loc только с поддержкой синхронизации нескольких потоков, хорошо, здесь понятно. Тогда получается от SemaphoreSlim он отличается лишь более сложным созданием т.к Semaphore(без имени) создается на уровне ядра и как следствие(из-за отсутствия имени) работает только для одного процесса(т.е толку от того, что он создается на уровни ядра никакого). Вот и получается, что SemaphoreSlim и Semaphore(без имени) буду работать одинаково, разве, что первый чуть быстрее. Правильно я понимаю расклад? Или же есть какое-то различие?

Comment: А при чем тут ядро ОС? :-)

Comment: Ну как я понял, область кода, доступ к которому синхронизируется с помощью Mutex находится в памяти Windows. Не внутри управляемой кучи которую у Windows запросила CLR. И доступ к этой области осуществляется через ядро. Ну я могу быть не прав)

Comment: В любом случаи я переименую тему)

Comment: С помощью Mutex можно синхронизировать не только доступ к коду :-)

Comment: Хм, не совсем понял, о чем вы. Если вы имеете виду синхронизации доступа к какому-нибудь файлу, то это тот же код, просто код записи данных в файл, к примеру) Мы же говорим об обычным C# коде, код помещается между методами WaitOne() и Release(). В результате этот код становится разделяемым ресурсом, доступ к которому и осуществляется

Comment: Некорректно называть 4 гига данных в оперативной памяти кодом, если синхронизация доступа к ним осуществляется через Mutex :-)

Comment: Я понял о чем вы, мы можем представить любые данные в памяти, но я поставил вопрос в контексте синтаксиса языка программирования C# ,поэтому была такая формулировка) В любом случаи спасибо за заметку

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Да, по смыслу неименованный Mutex — практически то же самое, что и блокировка через `lock`. Разница состоит в том, что

   - `lock` не работает через границы `AppDomain`'а, а неименованный `Mutex` доступен во всём процессе.
   - `Mutex` является `WaitHandle`'ом, то есть вы можете, например, дожидаться его с таймаутом или ждать блокировки одного из нескольких `Mutex`'ов.
   - `lock` реализован эффективнее, чем `Mutex`.
2. Разница между `Semaphore` и `SemaphoreSlim` примерно та же. `Semaphore` — обёртка над объектом Win32. `SemaphoreSlim` существенно быстрее, но он работает только внутри процесса и не экспортирует `WaitHandle`.

Comment: Фраза `Mutex является WaitHandle'ом, то есть вы можете пользовать, например, дожидаться его с таймаутом или ждать блокировки одного из нескольких Mutex'ов.` непонятна, поправьте, пожалуйста

Comment: @Андрей: Ага, исправил, спасибо!